# Rails PJAX Loading a partial not an html file

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, pjax

I am creating a tab based menu using PJAX in Rails.

I have PJAX working, it loads content in the correct div when I load a normal page. However I would like it just to load partials that contain snippets of content. For example when someone clicks "About" they load the partial "application/features" which is just a simple layout.

```
<%= link_to "About", {:render => 'application/features'}, :class =>"loader"%>
```

At the moment the above code loads nothing, Or the same page within the div. I.e. the page you load the link on gets reloaded inside the target div.

This is my pages.js

```
    $(function(){
   $('a.loader').pjax('#pjax')  
  })
```

I also have this in my controller

```
 def render(options = nil, extra_options = {}, &block)
    if request.headers['X-PJAX'] == 'true'
      options = {} if options.nil?
      options[:layout] = false 
    end
    super(options,&block)
  end
```

which stops the layout being rendered.

this is my div:

```
<div id="pjax"> 

</div>
```

All I really want to achieve is a partial being rendered. And if possible a way of highlighting the tab from which it was linked to. i.e current tab...

Answer (score 0):

So, I decided not to use PJAX in the end - instead i opted for Jquery Tools http://flowplayer.org/tools/

What I was looking for was a tab based system that enabled partials to be loaded. I did this by including a partial in the div that was rendered as the tab.

```
<div class="holder"><%= render 'pages/products/application/features'%></div>
```